# How do I resolve this syntax error I get when using the Perl conditional operator?

Tags: perl, syntax

I would like to get solution for a issue on in perl program.

```
$parallel_on=='YES'? my $pid = $pm->start and next; :0;
```

I want being the statement like this. but I am not getting solved. 
Can please any one solve this?

Comment: The semicolon bumping into the colon should be obvious enough. To put it differently: it's pretty obvious that you have a statement there that says "`:0`".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$parallel_on=='YES'? my $pid = $pm->start and next; :0;
```

There's a lot wrong there.  First, there's an extra semicolon; get rid of it.

```
$parallel_on=='YES'? my $pid = $pm->start and next :0;
```

Next, `=` and `and` have lower precedence than ?:, so you'd need to enclose the true condition in parentheses:

```
$parallel_on=='YES'? (my $pid = $pm->start and next) :0;
```

At this point, it will compile, but still not work.  == is for numeric comparisons, and 'YES', being a string not beginning with digits, has a numeric value of 0, so the condition is almost always going to be true.  (For example, 'NO'=='YES' is comparing 0==0, which is true.) Use eq instead:

```
$parallel_on eq 'YES'? (my $pid = $pm->start and next) :0;
```

The next part, I'm not sure how to help you with, since I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like.  `my $pid` declares a new lexical, with scope to the end of the enclosing block, but as soon as you assign to it, you use `next` to exit (and perhaps reenter) the block, thus losing the value you stored in $pid.  You probably want to declare $pid before the block.

```
my $pid;
...
    $parallel_on eq 'YES'? ( $pid = $pm->start and next) :0;
```

Now you have a `0;` hanging out, serving no purpose, when the condition is false.  Get rid of it:

```
    if ( $parallel_on eq 'YES' ) { $pid = $pm->start and next }
```

Unless you meant to assign it to $pid when the condition is false?

```
    $pid = $parallel_on eq 'YES' ? $pm->start : 0 and next;
```

Answer (score 4):

The ? : syntax is for assigning to variables, not for making one line if statements.  Since you are using two statements in the true part of the condition, do us all a favor and use a real if statement.  It's cleaner and you don't waste 5 minutes asking how to do it in SO.

```
my $pid = 0;

if ($parallel_on eq 'YES') {
    $pid = $pm->start;
    next;
}
```

Comment: Could have been stated with `--$snarkiness`, though.